# What do I need to import/mixin to make "noException" available in a scalatest?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'd like to write a test of the form `noException should be thrownBy myFunc()` as described in [Using Matchers](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingForExpectedExceptions)

I can't figure out what class I need to import to put `noException` in scope. I'm currently mixing in `Flatspec with ShouldMatchers`, and I've tried also doing it `with Matchers`

What am I missing?

In case it matters, I'm using scalatest 1.9.1 with scala 2.9:

```
scalaVersion := "2.9.3"
[...]
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalatest 2.0 added [`thrownBy`](http://www.scalatest.org/release_notes/2.0), and presumably `noException` came with it. You'll need to upgrade scalatest to a 2.x release, which also means upgrading scala to 2.10+